# CodeIgniter View Input Questions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

So, I've created a form in html/javascript for a site that leverages CodeIgniter. The data collected is inserted into a MySQL db. The next time a user comes back to that form, I want to repopulate this form with data from the db. So, some MySQL is run, and the view is called like:

```
$this->load->view('my_view', $data);
```

I'm able to insert elements from the $data array into html, like:

```
 <h2><?php echo $somevariable ?></h2>
```

But how would I reference a variable coming in from the $data[] array in the JS portion? I've tried things like:

```
if (<?php echo $somevariable ?> == 'Yes') { //do something  }
```

EDIT: This was solved by wrapping the left hand side of the comparison in quotes (Thank you Aniket!)

```
if ('<?php echo $somevariable ?>' == 'Yes') { //do something  }
```

This cumbersome way of handling things is thanks to CodeIgniter performing a call to PHP's extract() function on the data array between the Controller and the View. The array is no longer an array really, but a set of variables with their matching values. I wonder if there's a way to escape this. It would enable coders to just convert the $data array to an array of values JavaScript can easily read from, without having to hardcode indices.

Comment: We need to see some code and errors/issues.... and please try and make your questions as concise as possible

Comment: Sorry, was not familiar with StackExchange's method of displaying code, and I will edit it down.

Comment: please read over the [best page of the faq](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: this is far too vague

Comment: what kinds of code does $speaking_location echo???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is correct, but when PHP outputs something using `echo`, it just appears as plain text. You need to convert it into a string.

The following should work:

```
if ('<?php echo $speaking_location ?>' == 'Yes') { //do something  }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Everything else I can use workarounds for. Still need to look into setting default values for radio buttons and how to preselect values from dropdowns but this was the major roadblock. Much appreciated! If I could upvote this I would.

Comment: @JonasJSchreiber No problem, mate! I remember this because I have also gone through this stuff. And you can upvote this. Let me know if you need help anywhere else. Setting default values is very easy, there is a provision for it in CodeIgniter.

Comment: Apparently I need 15 reputation to upvote. Added your fix and a follow up above. I'm just going to add a "courtesy of Aniket" to the OP.

Comment: @JonasJSchreiber No need for that mate. It's a standard logic of the language.